# Update en base de datos (pdf) a mysql con PHP ayuda

Tags: php, html, ajax

ya intente muchas cosas

updatepdf.php

```
<?php
$archivo=$_FILES["pdf"]["name"];
  $tipo = $_FILES["pdf"]["type"];
    $tamanio = $_FILES["pdf"]["size"];
$ruta=$_FILES["pdf"]["tmp_name"];
$destino="cv/".$archivo;
//copy ($ruta, $destino);
    //conexión a la base de datos
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bd");
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
                echo "No se pudo conectar a la base de datos" .mysqli_connect_error();
            }       
$sid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["s_id"]);
            //insertamos los valores del formulario en nuestra bd
$sql = "UPDATE alumnos SET cvalu = '$destino' WHERE id_a = $sid";
            if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
                    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                } 
                else{ 
echo " <div align='center' class='alert alert-success '>Isertados con exito</div>";     
                    }
        ?>
```

formulario.html

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' id='formsubpdf'>

                    <label class='control-label'>Select File</label>
<div class='form-group'>
  <input id='file-0d' class='file' type='file' name='pdf' accept='application/pdf' >
        </div>

 <input type='text' required readonly class='form-control' name='s_id' id='idemp' value='$_SESSION['ses_id']' style='visibility:hidden; height:5px;'>             

            </form>
```

function.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('submit', '#formsubpdf', function() { 
console.log($(this).serialize()  ); 
        //obtenemos datos.
        var data = $(this).serialize();  

        $.ajax({  
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'subirpdf.php',
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
                  cache: false,
            processData:false,

            success :  function(data) {  
                $('#formsubpdf')[0].reset();
                $("#cargando").html(data);


            }
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

Esto es lo que utilizo en que estoy mal o que me falta ya me dolo la cabeza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) En el query estás tratando el id_a como un entero, y sin embargo lo estás escapeando a string  con mysql_real_escape_string.
Por ende: si el tipo de dato es un string (o varchar, en la BD), te faltan las comillas en el query:

```
"UPDATE alumnos SET cvalu = '$destino' WHERE id_a = '$sid'"
```

De todas formas, no es muy elegante que el primary key sea un string.
Si el id_a, por lo contrario, es un int (o un valor numérico) te recomiendo escapearlo como:

```
$sid = (int)$_POST["s_id"];
```

o algo por el estilo.

2) El archivo no lo estás subiendo an ningún lado. Te falta subir el archivo al servidor... Algo así como:

```
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pdf"]["tmp_name"],$destino)) {
    die("Error al subir el archivo");
}
```

3) Como recomendación, te faltan trapear algunos errores. $_FILES viene con un valor "error", en el cual te especifica si hubo un error a la hora de hacer el upload del archivo (por ejemplo, que excediste el límite máximo de tamaño establecido en el php.ini, o algo semejante). Si $_FILES tiene ese error, o si a mí en el form se me ocurre cambiarte (con el developer tools de chrome, por ejemplo) el nombre del campo de file en el formulario antes de postear, la aplicación te va a tirar muchos errores. Además, vas a estar haciendo update sobre archivos uqe no fueron subidos o que dieron error.
Si no tenés problemas con eso, joya. Si no, podrías hacer algo así como:

```
if(isset($_FILES['pdf']) && !$_FILES['pdf']['error']) {

    // etc...

} else {
    // Estrategia por si falló el archivo o no está seteado $_FILES['pdf']
}
```

El UPDATE hacelo siempre que estés SEGURO de que el archivo se subió. Si pasó TODAS las validaciones, ahí hacé el update.

Tu código final, debería quedar más o menos así (No es muy amigable que digamos, pero basado en el ejemplo, creo que funciona):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_FILES["pdf"]) && !$_FILES["pdf"])) {
        $archivo=$_FILES["pdf"]["name"];
        $tipo = $_FILES["pdf"]["type"];
        $tamanio = $_FILES["pdf"]["size"];
        $ruta=$_FILES["pdf"]["tmp_name"];
        $destino="cv/".$archivo;

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pdf"]["tmp_name"], $destino)) {
            //conexión a la base de datos
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bd");
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
                echo "No se pudo conectar a la base de datos" .mysqli_connect_error();
            }       
            $sid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["s_id"]);
            //insertamos los valores del formulario en nuestra bd
            $sql = "UPDATE alumnos SET cvalu = '$destino' WHERE id_a = $sid";
            if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            } 
            else { 
                echo " <div align='center' class='alert alert-success '>Isertados con exito</div>";     
            }
        } else {
            echo "Hubo un error en la subida del archivo.";
        }
    } else {
        if($_FILES["pdf"]['error'])) {
            echo "No se pudo subir el archivo. Razón: ". $_FILES["pdf"]['error'];
        } else {
            echo "No se pudo subir el archivo por alguna razón desconocida";
        }
    }
?>
```

Saludos y suerte!

Comment: Hola, tendrás un ejemplo de como cargar un archivo que esta en el servidor a un input file de un formulario de actualización, tengo registros en una DB incluyendo el nombre de archivos e imágenes, cree un formulario para actualizar los datos el formulario carga los datos de texto pero los input file no me carga los archivos de la bd o del servidor

Comment: Hola. No entiendo bien lo que necesitás. ¿Necesitás hacer un upload de archivos? O sea, ¿subir archivos a algun lado? 

El input file de html funciona con los archivos locales, es html. Corre en tu navegador, no en el servidor...